# Cakephp 2.1- login system using AuthComponent

Tags: authentication, logging, authorization, cakephp-2.0

I am going crazy with a problem for days now. I used the documentation and videos on youtube. Also some tutorials only about that particular issue. But there is something wrong that i can't see. I nedd a login system in a web system using cakephp.
 My table of users is the following:

```
    CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
    `Id` INT(50) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `grupo_id` INT(50) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `Status` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Coordenador/Bolsista/Super',
    `Nome` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `Login` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `Email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `Senha` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `created` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `modified` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `Login` (`Login`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `Nome` (`Nome`),
    INDEX `FK_usuarios_grupos` (`grupo_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_usuarios_grupos` FOREIGN KEY (`grupo_id`) REFERENCES `grupos` (`Id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
```

Where Status is the level of authorization for differente parts os the system. the 3 options are described in comments.

```
In my AppController, after some time, I coded:

    class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array('Session',
                               'Auth'=>array(
                                          'authenticate' => array(
                            'Form' => array(
                                           'fields'=>array(
                                                           'username'=>'Login',
                                                           'password'=>'Senha'
                                                            ),
                                    'userModel'=> 'Usuario'
                            ),
                           ),
                           'loginAction' =>array(
                                                    'Controller' => 'Usuarios',
                                                    'action' => 'login'
                                           ),
                'loginRedirect'=>array('Controller'=>'Usuarios', 'action'=>'index'), 
                'logoutRedirect'=>array('Controller'=>'Usuarios', 'action'=>'index'), 
                'authError'=>"You can't access that page", 
                'authorize'=>'Controller', 
                'loginError'=> 'Login errado'

            )
    );

    public function isAuthorized($usuario=null) {
        //return parent::isAuthorized($usuario);
        return true;
    }

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index','view');
        $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
        $this->set('current_user', $this->Auth->user());
    }
    }?>
```

The isAuthorized method has two options because i was trying things... The main problem is, every time i try to log in i go to the AuthError message. No matter if is a registered (with hashed password) or an invalid one. I do not see why this happens, but i suspect it is a issue with isAutorized method.

My specif controller has the following relevent methods:

```
public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());   
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
                $this->Session->setFlash('Username or password is incorrect');

            }
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }   
    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('add_bolsista','logout');
    }

    public function isAuthorized($usuario = null) {
        if (($usuario['Status'] == 'Super') || ($usuario['Status'] == 'Coordenador') || ($usuario['Status'] == 'Bolsista')) {
            return true;
        }
        if (in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete'))) {
            if ($usuario['Id'] != $this->request->params['pass'][0]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function isAuthorized($usuario = null) {
    // Any registered user can access public functions
    if (empty($this->request->params['Bolsista'])) {
        return true;
    }

    // Only admins can access admin functions
    if (isset($this->request->params['Super'])) {
        return (bool)($usuario['Status'] === 'Super');
    }

    // Default deny
    return false;
}
```

Two version of the isAuthorized...none seems to really work.
Anyone??

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to define isAuthorized method, if you only want to use the auth component for login system. Try once without this method.

You don't need to give logout method in allow() method in your specif controller, instead you should define 'login' into that, because this method will be accessible publicly. Hope it will work for you.